# How to find link in div where name begins with X

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to find a link where the name of the div begins with a certain text.

not OK when searching by "name begins with":

```
link = $("div[title^= 'label']").find('a').attr('href');
var contentOfFile = loadFile(link);
```

OK when searching by class:

```
link = $(".o_mail_thread").find('a').attr('href');
var contentOfFile = loadFile(link);
```

i'd like to get the content of a file, it works with an unique file as shown in "OK", but when there are multiple files, i can't select the right one based on this search "NOK".

Comment: DIVs don't have names, what do you mean by "name of the div begins with certain text"? Can you show an example of the HTML that you're trying to match?

Comment: If you search a certain `div` containing a particular string am not sure jquery will do the job but you will have to use `regexp` where you detect the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have some `div`s with class `o_mail_thread` and those `div`s have anchor element. `div`s dont have name. you have to select them by class

```
$('.o_mail_thread').each(() => {
    var link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    //do what you want with your links.
});
```

I didn't understand your `multiple file` reference. You have to share your full html code.